# cloud function read storage object data without using the storage client

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have created a simple cloud function with trigger: `google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized`

When a file (.xlsx) is being uploaded to my bucket I want to read it's content.

I am using following method for the same:

```
import functions_framework


@functions_framework.cloud_event
def process_data(cloud_event):
  print(f"Data: {cloud_event.data}")
```

I am able to print the cloud_event.data but how to I get the actual file which was uploaded

One way that I can do is using the storage client in below manner:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import functions_framework


def get_file(object_name, bucket_name, download_path):
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
  blob = bucket.blob(object_name)
  blob.download_to_filename(download_path)


@functions_framework.cloud_event
def process_data(cloud_event):
  print(f"Data: {cloud_event.data}")
  object_name = cloud_event.data['name']
  bucket_name = cloud_event.data['bucket']
  download_path = "/tmp/"
  get_file(object_name, bucket_name, download_path)
```

But is there a way through which I can get the actual contents of the file without using the cloud storage client ?

Comment: Why do you want to use another way that storage Python client ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun I am new to GCP and was wondering what was the proper way of read the cloud storage files from cloud function when the file is uploaded. 

is using cloud storage client ideal for such case ? if not then what else should we do.

Comment: Others can give their advice, but for me it’s ideal for such case and very simple to use. I prefer using cloud storage client in this case.